# AWS - AJAX request to Python Script on EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, ajax, python-3.x, reactjs, amazon-web-services

So I have a React app that I'm serving using Apache2 on an EC2 instance.  The app sends an AJAX (GET) request to a Python script on that same instance that uses natural language processing & web scraping tools to generate a summary of an article & returns a JSON object to be rendered appropriately in React.

The app works locally (I do npm start in one terminal to get the app running on localhost:3000, then another terminal for the python script at localhost:5000) but when I do this same setup on the EC2 instance I get a

`GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/?arg1=...&arg2=...  :ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

where `arg1` & `arg2` are the arguments I'm passing from React to the Python script.

I also have this function in my Python script to allow for cross-domain requests...

```
@app.after_request 
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response
```

My question is why does it work different on an EC2 than my local computer and how would I begin going about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Are you using API Gateway at all with the EC2 instance? You also may need to have a header for authorization token. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html

Comment: No, I am not using an API Gateway.